# Silex, using Twig in service

Tags: php, twig, silex, pimple

I'm creating an application in Silex. I want to use Twig to render templates in my service which is loading by Pimple. I need this for mailer class.

I started writing application based on silex-skeleton, so I have an twig environment in $app['twig']. The problem is, when I want to pass it into a service:

```
//app.php
$app['someModel'] = function ($app) {
    return new someModel($app['twig']);
};
```

When I'm writing something like this, twig stops working. All my subpages show:

> Twig_Error_Loader: Template "(path).html.twig" is not defined ().

I've tried another trick:

```
//app.php
$app['someModel'] = function ($app) {
    return new someModel($app);
};

//someModel.php
class SomeModel
{
    private $twig;

    public function __construct($app)
    {
        $this->twig = $app['twig'];
    }
}
```

but that also breaks the twig. I've tried to assign and clone an $app['twig'] to another variable, then it also happens.

```
//app.php
$variable = $app['twig']

//app.php
$variable = clone $app['twig']
```

How can I use Twig in service in Silex?

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), 
  array('twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));
```

To get more information have a look into the [Silex Documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html).

Comment: I have registered Twig provider, like [here](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton/blob/master/src/app.php) and my site is normally working. The problem is, twig breaks when I try to put it in the service.

Comment: What do you mean with 'twig breaks'?

Comment: When I put $app['twig'] to a service by pimple, then all my subpages which before normally working, show: Twig_Error_Loader: Template "(path).html.twig" is not defined ().

Comment: I assume you have a problem with dependency injection, a proper way is like this:

`use Silex\Application;
    
    class Sample
    {
      protected $app = null;

      public function __construct(Application $app)
      {
        $this->app = $app;
      }
    }`